# Display archive by selecting year and then selecting month

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-plugins, archive

I'm trying to build my archive page to have a row of years and a row of months. The user would then have to select a year and then select a month and a gallery of posts would be generated. I have an example image below of what I want. How could I achieve this? I've searched online and I can't find anything similar to this. I have added a mockup html and css of how it should look, but I just can't figure out how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated! I have a code pen of the html and css here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpZqr

what I want...
[image]

my current page-archive.php

```html
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>ARCHIVE</h1>
</div>
<div class="archive-block">
 <span class="archive-block__alert">
  Please Select A Year First </span>
 <ul class="archive-block__list archive-block__list--year">

     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2009">
     2009    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2010">
     2010    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2011">
     2011    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2012">
     2012    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2013">
     2013    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2014">
     2014    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2015">
     2015    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2016">
     2016    </span>
   </li>
     <li class="archive-block__item ">
    <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year archive-block__selector--current-year" data-year="2017">
     2017    </span>
   </li>
  
 </ul>

 <ul class="archive-block__list archive-block__list--month">
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month archive-block__selector--current-month" data-month="1">
           Jan          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="2">
           Feb          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="3">
           Mar          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="4">
           Apr          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="5">
           May          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="6">
           Jun          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="7">
           Jul          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="8">
           Aug          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="9">
           Sep          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="10">
           Oct          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="11">
           Nov          </span>
         </li>
               <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
         <li class="archive-block__item">
          <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="12">
           Dec          </span>
         </li>
   </ul>
</div>


<div class="archive-block__empty-con">
 <span class="archive-block__empty">
  That combination is empty! Please select a different combination </span>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and css

```css
.archive-block {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.archive-block__alert {
    display: none;
}
.archive-block__list {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.archive-block__list--month {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.archive-block__empty-con {
    text-align: center;
}


.archive-block__item {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 23.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to capture the user's selected dates(year and month) then make a ajax call to fetch posts by date range and populate the result.

Take a look at: [wp_get_archives()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) function for more details.